# Can I have variables inside of JSDOC

Tags: javascript, node.js, jsdoc

I have several functions that share some underlying data structure, while also doing very different things, such that abstraction isn't really a good idea.

Documentation might look like this (although this is just a small sample and many methods share only some of this documentation):

```
/**
 * Creates an array of objects, with each object containing the average distance that minute. The
 * objects have the keys **Timestamp** (ms since epoch), **Year** (year in device local time) **Month** (
 * month in device local time), **Day** (day in device local time), **Hour** (hour in device local time)
 * **Season** (season in device local time, Northern Hemisphere), **Weekday** (Week day name in device
 * local time), **WeekNum** (week number (1-53) in device local time), **Depth** (the average depth that
 * minute), and **Vibration** (the magnitude of the maximum acceleration for the minute, in Gs).
 * <snip>
 */

/**
 * Creates an array of objects, with each object containing the data for one minute of temperature data
 * from temperature probes. The objects have the keys **Timestamp** (ms since epoch), **Year** (year in
 * device local time) **Month** (month in device local time), **Day** (day in device local time), **Hour**
 * (hour in device local time) **Season** (season in device local time, Northern Hemisphere), **Weekday**
 * (Week day name in device local time), **WeekNum** (week number (1-53) in device local time),
 * **Temperature** (Temperature measured by the temperature probe), **Vib**(the standard deviation of the
 * acceleration of the accelerometer, in Gs).
 * <snip>
 */
```

As you can see from the sample, my documentation of vibration and what it means is inconsistent. I don't want to have to go and fix the documentation in 6 places each time I change what it means (or even worse, the hardware engineers change what it means). Is there a way for me to have a global dictionary of terms and insert it as appropriate? Something like:

```
terms.json
    > {vibDef: "the magnitude of the maximum acceleration for the minute, in Gs"}

code.js
    > /**
       * Creates an array of objects, with each object containing the average distance that minute. The
       * objects have the keys **Timestamp** (ms since epoch), **Year** (year in device local time) **Month** (
       * month in device local time), **Day** (day in device local time), **Hour** (hour in device local time)
       * **Season** (season in device local time, Northern Hemisphere), **Weekday** (Week day name in device
       * local time), **WeekNum** (week number (1-53) in device local time), **Depth** (the average depth that
       * minute), and **Vibration** (<<vibDef>>).
       * <snip>
       */
```

That would insert my definition of vibDef everywhere it's found in the doc strings?

Comment: Last time I used jsdoc, you could hook up your own parsers (we used it for markdown), so adding one for your glossary tags should be possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the suggestion of @ssube, I wrote a plugin that expands text write between `!>` and `<!` into longer definitions, saved in a global file. For the record, here it is:

```
var globalDict = require('../globals.js').jsDoc;


exports.handlers = {
    beforeParse: function(e) {
        var reg = /!>(?=\S)(\w+)(?=\S)<!/;
        do {
            m = reg.exec(e.source);
            if (m) {
                var originalTxt = m[0];
                var expandedDef = globalDict[m[1]];
                if (expandedDef) {
                    e.source = e.source.replace(originalTxt, expandedDef);
                } else {
                    e.source = e.source.replace(originalTxt, m[1]); // Prevent infinite loop
                    console.log('Error: Missing definition for jsDoc keyword', m[1]);
                }
            }
        } while (m);
    }
};
```

globals.js looks like:

```
exports.jsDoc = {
    vibration: "twice the standard deviation in the recorded acceleration over the course of a minute"
};
```